# PyTables create_array fails to save numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, pytables

Why does the snipped below give:

*"TypeError: Array objects cannot currently deal with void, unicode or object arrays"*?

**Python 3.8.2, tables 3.6.1, numpy 1.19.1**

```
import numpy as np
import tables as tb
TYPE = np.dtype([
    ('d', 'f4')
])
with tb.open_file(r'c:\temp\file.h5', mode="a") as h5file:
    h5file.create_group(h5file.root, 'grp')
    arr = np.array([(1.1)], dtype=TYPE)
    h5file.create_array('/grp', str('arr'), arr)
```

Comment: The `dtype` is wrong.  I think `h5py` will work with this dtype, but evidently oytables has not inplemented it.  Did you read pytables docs?

Comment: h5py does not install in my Pycharm venv with many installation problems.
I read the docs and numpy arrays are supposed to be supported. I am not sure what is the difference between numpy array with or without dtype in this context.

Comment: Arrays in general may be supported, but not all dtypes.  h5py can't save object dtypes.  You have a structured array with a compound dtype (the void in the error massage)

Comment: Thanks  hpaulj, In that case I will convert it to straight ndarray before saving and apply the dtype after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

`File.create_array()` is for homogeneous dtypes (all ints, or all floats, etc). PyTables uses a different object to save mixed dytpes. You need to use `File.create_table()` instead. See modified code below (only the last line changed).

```
TYPE = np.dtype([ ('d', 'f4') ])
with tb.open_file(r'c:\temp\file.h5', mode="a") as h5file:
    h5file.create_group(h5file.root, 'grp')
    arr = np.array([(1.1)], dtype=TYPE)
    h5file.create_table('/grp', str('arr'), arr)
```

Note: you will get an error with `mode='a'` if you run with an existing `temp.h5` file from your previous work. This is due to a conflict with  group `/grp` created the first time.